# What does it mean if a question is green?

Tags: support, question-lists

What does the green on the questions title mean?

[image]

and why is 180 not green even though -3 is green?

Does the green mean it has many views?

Comment: Where's link to previously-asked, possibly-duplicate question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question is green, it means it has an accepted answer. The OP has chosen an answer which he found the most helpful. If it is not present, it means the OP hasn't selected an answer by clicking the tick under the vote button.

See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/357396) for more details.